# Apache out of memory and restarts at 1GB of RAM

Tags: wordpress, windows, apache, bitnami

I have issue that I'm trying to resolve for some time. I'm using Bitnami WordPress version on Windows VM and server works fine, but when Apache reaches 1GB of RAM it automatically restarts and in error log I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory
```

I tried so many configurations and the problem is not so common now, but it happens all over again when **httpd.exe** process reaches 1GB of RAM.

Here is my VM setup:

- **VM OS:** Windows Server 2016 - 64bit
- **RAM:** 4 GB
- **CPU**: 4 processors

**WP-CONFIG.php:**

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '3000M' );
```

**httpd.conf:**

```
Timeout 10
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

**httpd-mpm.conf:**

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild      300
    MaxRequestsPerChild    0
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    MaxMemFree            2048
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    MaxMemFree             100
</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess:**

```
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value max_execution_time 120
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
```

Any idea/solution how can I fix those restarts when Apache Server (httpd.exe) reaches 1GB of RAM?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Hi, there is a known issues in the Bitnami stack where the .htaccess is not empty. It should contain a comment indicating to check out INSTALLDIR/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf instead. Could you try to add the PHP configuration there?

Comment: Hi @marcosbc. Thanks for your answer. I haven't added my PHP configures in htaccess.conf, but I done that now so I will follow how the server will work.  Thanks for your answer!